# Can a capital loss on a gilt be set against the interest received when tax is calculated?

Tags: taxes, bonds, capital-gains-tax, capital-loss

Say if I buy a 3.75% gilt for £103, with a redemption date 1 year from now, then at the the end of the year I should receive £3.75 interest from coupons, but I lose £3 of capital. The total gain is £0.75.

Do I need to pay tax on £3.75 (which is the interest I received) or £0.75 which is the money I actually made ?

I am an overseas investor and the gilt is not taxed in the UK if that makes any difference.

Comment: Which country's tax code are you asking about? Tax questions need a country tag.